# Problem encountered when reinstalling XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm using macOS Version 12.0.1. So, what's happening is, I reinstalled XAMPP, and so when I clicked started, it started and showed me my IP address. Next, when I went to the services and tried to start all Apache, MySQL and ProFTPD, none of them started, and it said this in the log:

```
ERROR: Failed to start "proftpd": cannot start service: bash: /opt/lampp/ctlscript.sh: No such file or directory

ERROR: Failed to start "mysql": cannot start service: bash: /opt/lampp/ctlscript.sh: No such file or directory

ERROR: Failed to start "apache": cannot start service: bash: /opt/lampp/ctlscript.sh: No such file or directory
```

So, then when I was clueless, I decided to check the files in Lampp. So, I mounted XAMPP and then clicked on Lampp, and these are the only files it showed:

[XAMPP Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NwCu.png)

There are supposed to be so many more files, but there weren't here, so that's why none of the services/stacks were starting. To try and fix this, I restarted my computer, reinstalled XAMPP a couple of times (even on different versions), but nothing worked.

Hopefully, this is possible to resolve. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. When ever I reinstall xampp (windows), I do the following. 1. Disable antivirus. 2. UAC (user account control) is set to never notify. 3. run install as administrator. This way I don't have any problems. I dont know about UAC in mac.

Comment: share your error log for reference

Comment: @Buttered_Toast So what do I do right now?

Comment: @newt What? I just showed you right now I only have those four, I don't have an error log. I'm asking what I should do as of now??

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling following my steps? if that doesnt help best option is to check the official documentation.

Comment: I'm on Mac so I don't know how to do your steps and could you please give me the steps, one by one for clarity, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: And honestly I would like to just erase my XAMPP and set it up again. I have backups of my project and databases anyways, but whenever I reinstall, the same files on show up, it doesn't reinstall properly with all the files...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you install xampp if mac already provide you with mysql default
Uninstall xampp and Try mac command

```
Brew install PHP
Brew install MySQL
```

If not work then try this blog https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-catalina/
May it help you
Thanks.

Comment: So in what steps should I do. Should I uninstall then run these commands on the XAMPP terminal or what?